# Missing ")" in a rails template file

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, erb

I am working on a rails project and am unable to identify the source of the error : `SyntaxError: [stdin]:10:26: missing )` when i render `application.html.erb`.

[image]

From the template i can't find the cause of the error or how to fix it.

Am using `Rails 5.1.6`

**application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>App</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= tag :meta, name: :psj, action: action_name, controller: controller_name %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Isolating code sections shows that the error is being triggered by either including the lines containing  ** javascript_include_tag ** or **stylesheet_link_tag**

Comment: Might be worth posting the whole file. Not sure we can help with just the snippet.

Comment: Thanks for your response, just added the entire file as requested.

Comment: I would guess that it's something that's getting loaded around line 8 and not the file you've posted, that has the error. Are there more console messages? Can you show them all if so?

Comment: No that's all I get from the console. Except you want a full stack trace.

Comment: what ruby version?

Comment: Also check your stylesheets/javascripts, the error likely comes from there.

Comment: Ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [i386-mingw32]

Comment: A stack trace would be helpful. Also what web server are you using? Is the logging level something you can change? Are you saying that when you click on a page and it goes to render application.html.erb it ONLY produces one sentence? You don't see the request?